# Problem with php_pdo_oci installation on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: php, extension

I need to install PDO_OCI for PHP on my localhost (Ubuntu).
I'm not expert at linux packages/dependencies so please correct me if somewhere in my thoughts I am wrong.
When I try to use pecl ( `sudo pecl install pdo_oci` )it says:

```
pear/PDO_OCI requires PHP extension "pdo" (version >= 1.0)
```

but believe PDO is installed (`ls -la /usr/lib/php5/20121212/ | grep -c pdo.so` says 1).
I found a tutorial on the web to build pdo_oci myself (http://bencornwell.com/112/) so I followed and with some struggle obtained `pdo_oci.so`.
Unfortunately it doesn't load giving me the message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_oci.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_oci.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_stmt_delref in Unknown on line 0
```

I assume it may be something with php / pdo_oci version uncompatibility but I don't have knowledge and experience to know how to deal with this situation.
What can I do to make this work?
 My system info:
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 (cli) (built: Oct 29 2014 11:59:10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe i handled it myself. There were two things that i needed to change.
1. pdo_oci.so was being loaded before pdo.so. I changed the order and the error message has been modified.
2. I compiled pdo_oci directly from the source code for my version of php (I followed instructions on: http://blog.appwhoosh.com/install-pdo_oci-oci8-extensions-for-ubuntu-14-10/).
Now the extension works perfectly.

Comment: number 1 for me. I just change filename /etc/php.d/oracle.ini to /etc/php.d/pdo_oracle.ini makes pdo.so load first.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the Oracle drivers, you can use this [this class here](https://github.com/taq/pdooci) and then you just need to change your PDO connection from something like

```
$pdo = new PDO("oci:dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8", "user", "password");
```

to

```
$pdo = new PDOOCI\PDO("mydatabase", "user", "password");
```

The rest should work exactly the same as if you were using a PDO object.